# SQL - Carry forward derived column value while another column is populated

Tags: sql, teradata

I am using Teradata 16.20. 
Suppose I have the following data in a table.

This is a small subset, there are over a dozen columns and thousands of Users with multiple rows, each time a value changes in a column for a user, a new row is inserted with a specific as_of_dt. It is a transaction log for changes to a user.

```
╔══════╦════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ User ║  As_Of_DT  ║ Job_Location ║ temp_asgn ║
╠══════╬════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ ABC  ║ 2018.01.01 ║ MT           ║           ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.01.15 ║ MT           ║           ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.02.01 ║ SD           ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.03.01 ║ SD           ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.03.15 ║ MT           ║           ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.05.01 ║ TX           ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.06.01 ║ TX           ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.07.01 ║ TX           ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.09.01 ║ MT           ║           ║
║ ABC  ║ 2019.01.01 ║ AZ           ║           ║
║ ABC  ║ 2019.02.01 ║ TX           ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2019.03.01 ║ AZ           ║           ║
╚══════╩════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

A new column called Home_Job_Location is needed which is populated as follows:

When the temp_asgn field is blank, then set Home_Job_Location to Job_Location.

Otherwise use the Job_Location value from the row *before temp_asgn* is populated, and bring it forward in Home_Job_Location until temp_asgn is no longer populated. Like this:

```
╔══════╦════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ User ║  As_Of_DT  ║ Job_Location ║ Base_Job_Location ║ temp_asgn ║
╠══════╬════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ ABC  ║ 2018.01.01 ║ MT           ║ MT                ║           ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.01.15 ║ MT           ║ MT                ║           ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.02.01 ║ SD           ║ MT                ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.03.01 ║ SD           ║ MT                ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.03.15 ║ MT           ║ MT                ║           ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.05.01 ║ TX           ║ MT                ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.06.01 ║ TX           ║ MT                ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.07.01 ║ TX           ║ MT                ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2018.09.01 ║ MT           ║ MT                ║           ║
║ ABC  ║ 2019.01.01 ║ AZ           ║ AZ                ║           ║
║ ABC  ║ 2019.02.01 ║ TX           ║ AZ                ║ Y         ║
║ ABC  ║ 2019.03.01 ║ AZ           ║ AZ                ║           ║
╚══════╩════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

I've tried 2 things ordering by as_of_date

I've tried 
`LAG(job_location) over (partition by person_id order by as_of_date)`,  this works if there is only 1 row chronologically with temp_asgn, but there could be any number of "temp_asgn" rows for the value to be carried through.

I also tried
 first_value/last_value but the partition doesn't work. Including the temp_asgn column in the partition means there are two partitions instead of one , and not including temp_asgn just gets me the first/last value chronologically.

A general solution would be helpful, there are several of these columns in this table that I have to do this for based on if temp_asgn is populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the temporary location to NULL and apply LAST_VALUE plus the IGNORE NULLS option:

```
Last_Value(CASE WHEN temp_asgn IS NULL THEN job_location END IGNORE NULLS)
Over (PARTITION BY person_id
      ORDER BY as_of_date)
```